# Jenkins: Is there any way to use the build number in the configuration screen for a job?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I use the build # through the environment with many tools to generate reports and such.  Some new plugins looks like they might be fun to use on some of those files, but in order to supply the file path, I need to use the current build # in the job configuration screen for that plugin...

Is there anyways to get the build # as a variable for the configuration screen for plugins?

Comment: Try giving `${BUILD_NUMBER}` in the job configuration screen and check if it works.

Comment: That worked.  Why don't you post that as an answer so I can give you a bump in your rep. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try giving `${BUILD_NUMBER}` in the job configuration screen and check if it works.